# Forcing flash on canon Ixus 240?

Tags: canon, flash, canon-ixus

Bought a canon ixus 240 off ebay a few months back and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to force flash on. The two settings that are available to me are either no flash or auto flash which isn’t great. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the [camera manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300008070/01/Ixus_510HS_Ixus_240HS_CameraUserGuide_EN_v2.00.pdf)? It seems to indicate the following on page 122:

[image: Screenshot from page 122 of the camera manual showing menu procedure to force flash on]